# how to smartly extract elements from 3 D array and put it into one array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

lets say

```
g(:,:,1) = [ 1;   4;  7]
g(:,:,2) = [11;  44; 77]  
g(:,:,3) = [111; 444; 777] .
```

Lets say `a = [2; 3; 1]`  and `b = [1; 3; 2]`. I want the output like this 
`[4;777;11]`.  first element is `g(2,:,1)` , second element is `g(3,:,3)` and third element is `g(1,:,2)`.

Comment: It's not that simple as you think

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind the kinda formula "a+(col_num -1)*m + (b-1)*m*n)" . I cannot understand. Could you please derive that formula. please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this -

```
[m,n,r] = size(g)
out = g(a + (b-1)*m*n)
```

For a generic case, when you want to specify the column number as well -

```
out = g(a + (col_num-1)*m + (b-1)*m*n)
```

For a more generic case, when you want to specify more than just one column -

```
g(bsxfun(@plus,(col_nums-1)*m,a(:)+(b(:)-1)*m*n))
```

For even more generic cases, you have to ask *harder* questions.

Sample run -

```
>> g
g(:,:,1) =
    11    81    26    19    87
    96    87    80    27    58
     1     9    43    15    55
    77    40    91    14    15
g(:,:,2) =
    85    40    19    90    34
    62     8    24    94    90
    35    24    42    49    37
    51    13     5    49    12
g(:,:,3) =
    78    10    57    82    65
    39    14     6     2    73
    24    94    24     5    65
    40    95    35    17    45
>> [m,n,r] = size(g);
>> a = [2,3,1]; b = [1,3,2];
>> col_nums = [1 3];
>> g(bsxfun(@plus,(col_nums-1)*m,a(:)+(b(:)-1)*m*n))
ans =
    96    80
    24    24
    85    19
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind the kinda formula "a+(col_num -1)*m + (b-1)*m*n)" . I cannot understand. Could you please derive that formula. please?

Comment: @bepracticalalwayz MATLAB follows column major indexing. In your case, `a` is the row ID and `b` is the dimension-3 ID. That solution calculates the linear indices and uses those to extract specific elements. So, `b` is to be "jumped" `mxn` times i.e. size of a 3D slice. The added term `col_num` is to be "jumped" `m` times for the same reason. I suggest you go through [`this tutorial on linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). It has way more good stuffs that goes through all of this.

Comment: @Divakar I didn't know  about this. I wrote another function for this job kinda dumb way. Now I can write the code more efficiently. thanks a lot

Comment: @bepracticalalwayz Awesome!

Comment: Linear indexing for the win!

Comment: @bepracticalalwayz don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. thanks!